Upgrade from .NET 6 to .NET 8 Erroring with " Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration, Version=8.0.0.0'"
I am currently trying to update an API repo from .net6.0 to .net8.0, as well as update the Cosmos database from 2.13.1 to 3.35.4. I believe the data base upgrade is fine and so is the app service for the API. It's just the change feed function that is erroring out when tryin to test it locally. This is the first repo to be updated to 8.0 so it's a learning experience.
First, here is the error I'm receiving.

Here's what I've tried:

Reviewed all packages, looking for where the Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration is defined.
Loaded version 8.0.0 of the package, hoping that it would override any other packages where a lower version is defined.

I found the Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration package defined at my domain level within one of our nuget packages, Columbia.Cosmos.Common as well at the function level in Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.
Here is the csproj file for the domain level:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
      <GenerateTargetFrameworkAttribute>false</GenerateTargetFrameworkAttribute>
    <ImplicitUsings>disable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="Consumer\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="Consumer\**" />
    <None Remove="Consumer\**" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="cdtservicecommon" Version="[*,9999.0]" />
    <PackageReference Include="Columbia.Cosmos.Common" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" Version="2.20.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos" Version="3.46.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.App" Version="2.2.8" />

  </ItemGroup>

</Project>


And this is the csproj file for the change feed functions:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus" Version="7.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Columbia.ServiceBus.Common" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="csc.azure.datalake.client" Version="4.0.0-preview1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB" Version="3.0.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="5.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Polly" Version="6.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Polly" Version="7.2.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Polly.Contrib.WaitAndRetry" Version="1.1.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\cscentconsumer.infrastructure\cscentconsumer.infrastructure.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>


And lastly, here is the startup.cs for the function that is erroring out:
using CdtServiceCommon.Domain.Interfaces;
using CdtServiceCommon.Infrastructure.Logging;
using Columbia.Cosmos.Common.Extensions;
using Columbia.Cosmos.Common.FaultTolerance;
using csc.azure.datalake.client.Extensions;
using cscentconsumer.domain.Models.Consumer;
using CscEntConsumer.Infrastructure.Configuration;
using CscEntConsumer.Infrastructure.Repository;
using CscEntConsumerFunctions;
using CscEntConsumerFunctions.Configuration;
using CscEntConsumerFunctions.Utilities;
using CscEntConsumerFunctions.Utilities.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System;
using System.Linq;

[assembly: WebJobsStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace CscEntConsumerFunctions
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            IConfigurationRoot config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                                        .SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory)
                                        .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                                        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                                        .Build();

            builder.Services.AddDatalakeClient(options => config.Bind(options));

            builder.Services.AddSingleton(config);

            builder.Services.AddCosmosDb(
                config.GetValue<string>("cosmosdb-connection"),
                options =>
                {
                    options.DatabaseId = config["CosmosDb:DatabaseId"];
                    options.Containers = config["CosmosDb:Containers"].Split(',').ToList();
                },
                cosmosResiliencySettings: config.GetValue<CosmosResiliencySettings>("CosmosResiliencySettings"));

            builder.Services.AddOptions();
            builder.Services.Configure<ConsumerServiceDetails>(config.GetSection("ServiceDetails"));
            builder.Services.Configure<DataLakeConfiguration>(config);

            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IModelMasterRepository<Consumer>, ConsumerMasterRepository>();
            builder.Services.AddUpserterAsSingleton<IModelMasterRepository<Consumer>, Consumer, string>();

            builder.Services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, TelemetryInitializer>();
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IMessageBuilderUtility, MessageBuilderUtility>();
        }
    }
}

Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated! Let me know if you need to see anything else to help research the issue. Thanks in advance!

Check that all your Microsoft.Extensions.* packages are updated to version 8.0.0 or higher. Check your csproj files and update the following packages.

The error suggests that there is a version mismatch between the assemblies. check all assemblies versions.

Try to add Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration explicitly in Ver 8.x and check if Columbia.Cosmos.Common is fine with that.
Btw. you also might update Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions to a newer version.

I added the Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration package to the domain project and I see it updated to 9.0.0 in Columbia.Cosmos.Common, but when I attempt to run the function locally I get the same error, but now it says it can't load Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration, Version=9.0.0.0

Upgrade versions of the assemblies Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions to 4.5.0 and Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB to 4.8.1.
Add  "FUNCTIONS_INPROC_NET8_ENABLED": "1" in local.settings.json.
local.settings.json:
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_INPROC_NET8_ENABLED": "1",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "COSMOS_CONNECTION": "<CosmosDB_Connection_String>"
  }
}

.csproj:
Update all the packages to latest versions.
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus" Version="7.18.2" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB" Version="4.8.1" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="5.16.4" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Polly" Version="9.0.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.5.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Polly" Version="8.5.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Polly.Contrib.WaitAndRetry" Version="1.1.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

I have created a .NET 8.0 Cosmos DB trigger Azure function and able to get the expected response.

Functions:

        Function1: cosmosDBTrigger

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-12-02T11:56:32.345Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000F72731CC'.
[2024-12-02T11:58:07.764Z] Executing 'Function1' (Reason='New changes on container container1 at 2024-12-02T11:58:07.7394366Z', Id=0997cc56-624d-4e74-9631-2332d3ee63dd)
[2024-12-02T11:58:07.778Z] Documents modified 1
[2024-12-02T11:58:07.781Z] First document Id 1
[2024-12-02T11:58:07.795Z] Executed 'Function1' (Succeeded, Id=0997cc56-624d-4e74-9631-2332d3ee63dd, Duration=50ms)


Unfortunately, making the updates your suggested did not solve the problem.

Did you add FUNCTIONS_INPROC_NET8_ENABLED:1 in local.settings.json?

Interesting..... I pushed up my branch and a coworker pull down the repo and it ran fine locally in his version of VS. I found that he has VS Enterprise and I have VS Professional. I have all the latest updates for my version, so I'm not sure if the issue is because I don't have Enterprise edition?
Anyone heard of anything like this?

I have tried in VS Community, and it worked. Try with the code I have provided in answer above.

Thank you, everyone for your input. Would you believe there was nothing wrong with the repo?!! It was my version of VS. I was running professional which had a different runtime version than enterprise.
When I upgraded to enterprise edition the local test ran fine. I was chasing my tail for no reason. Lol. Anyway, thanks again!
